# How to use $(this) properly

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am creating a jquery codes that makes each images disappears once the image was click. I am using the same images however when I click on each it doesn't hide the one that was click instead it hides the images from the bottom to top.

Here's my jQuery code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });

});
```

Any idea?

Comment: The code is working. Image deletion causes subsequent images to shift. Try using different URls

Comment: If you click on one image the other image will disappear. What I want to attain is when I click on the image the "CLICKED" image will be the one to disappear.

Comment: **No**. Please verify once again using different URls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually really is hiding the element clicked on.

However, it seems it is hiding from bottom to top because when you click a top element, that element is hidden, and lower elements *slide up* in its place.

To prove this to your self, try adding `title` attributes to the images

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('img').click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
      });

    });
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300
}
#wrapper {
  width: 71%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
img {
  border: 6px solid #f1c40f;
  margin: 20px 22px 0px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <img src="http://goo.gl/CIHVmL" title="image 1" />
  <img src="http://goo.gl/CIHVmL" title="image 2" />
  <img src="http://goo.gl/CIHVmL" title="image 3" />
  <img src="http://goo.gl/CIHVmL" title="image 4" />
  <img src="http://goo.gl/CIHVmL" title="image 5" />
  <img src="http://goo.gl/CIHVmL" title="image 6" />
  <img src="http://goo.gl/CIHVmL" title="image 7" />
  <img src="http://goo.gl/CIHVmL" title="image 8" />
</section>
```

Comment: Still it doesn't fix it. It must hide the exact image "CLICKED"

Comment: @KimberlyWright, it is hiding the exact image clicked. To prove it, before you click the image, wait for the title to come up, example `image 1`. Click it, afterwards, the next image will go in its place and the title will be `image 2`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').click(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Try this for you to know that your code is working :)

Answer (score 0):

Ouwh, your code is working. You did't see that because all the image were same. Change the image and you can see what the code actually doing. Test this code.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('img').click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
      });

    });
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300
}
#wrapper {
  width: 71%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
img {
  border: 6px solid #f1c40f;
  margin: 20px 22px 0px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <img src="http://goo.gl/CIHVmL" style="border:6px solid green" />
  <img src="http://goo.gl/CIHVmL" style="border:6px solid red" />
  <img src="http://goo.gl/CIHVmL" style="border:6px solid blue" />
  <img src="http://goo.gl/CIHVmL" />
  <img src="http://goo.gl/CIHVmL" />
  <img src="http://goo.gl/CIHVmL" />
  <img src="http://goo.gl/CIHVmL" />
  <img src="http://goo.gl/CIHVmL" />
</section>
```

Comment: Yeah however, the "EXACT CLICKED" image doesn't disappear.

Comment: Tried adding title tag but doesn't fixed the issue.

Comment: @KimberlyWright what you mean does't disappear. I try to make three of image with different border color. Try click the colored images border with blue, green and red.